# Excel -When a date is entered into a cell on one sheet, a corresponding number is entered into another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am setting up a recurring bill system in excel. I have 2 working sheets, one named finance, and one Dates.
The set up the same across both. Column A is bill, B is amount, and c is frequency & dates of week-ending in each column from D onwards. (D-BA)

The difference is Finance sheet contains the amounts due each week, while Dates sheet contains the actual due date of the bill.
What I am ideally after is a way to automate a process for if a date is entered in any cell on Dates sheet, it will enter the corresponding amount in the same cell on the Finance sheet. Example if I add a date in cell G4 on Dates sheet, it will automatically enter the number in B4 on Finance sheet. The number it will draw from will always be in B column of that row. eg. date entered on Dates sheet P17 will enter data on Finance sheet in cell P17 from B17.
I have tried the following -

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim FinanceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim FinanceRange As Range
    Dim DateCell As Range
    
    ' Set the Finance sheet and range
    Set FinanceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Finance")
    Set FinanceRange = FinanceSheet.Range("C:D")
    
    ' Check if the change occurred in the Dates sheet and if it's a date
    If Target.Worksheet.Name = "Dates" And IsDate(Target.Value) Then
        ' Find the corresponding cell in the Finance sheet
        Set DateCell = FinanceSheet.Range("C:C").Find(Target.Address, LookIn:=xlValues)
        
        ' Check if a matching cell was found
        If Not DateCell Is Nothing Then
            ' Enter the corresponding amount from Finance sheet in the same cell
            FinanceSheet.Range("B" & DateCell.Row).Value = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Additionally, if I can reference whatever is entered in row 26 on Finance sheet to populate to same cell on Dates sheet.
TIA

I cannot work out anything for the first problem.
If have done =Finance!E26 for example on each individual cell in row 26 dates sheet. Surely there is an easy way to track the whole row?

Comment: Please check this link: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `Target.EntireRow.Columns("B").Value` is the value in ColB on the same row as `Target`